# jquery hover open close miniature window

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

```
 <div id="pop">
 <ul>
      <li>Item 1</li>
      <li>Item 2</li>
      <li>Item 3</li>
      <li>Item 4</li>
      <li>Item 5</li>
      <li>Item 6</li>
      <li>Item 7</li>
 </ul>
 </div>
 <div id="info-1></div>
 <div id="info-2></div>
```

And when you hover over one of the items a window is displayed with some info regarding the item. I have worked this out for one item, now I wanna know how I can make this work for the entire list.

My initial thought was to create one script per each item... but that seems a bit thick considering the functionality of js.

Javascript

```
 $(function(){
 $('pop il li').hover(function(){
      $('#info-1').show();
 },function(){
      $('#info-1').hide();
 });
```

});

Now I need the following. Once the "window" is displayed on hover, in I need the window to stay open in some way for me to be able to scroll through the content using my mouse. This is mainly because I have some links inside it and need to access them! Right now, As soon as i leave the li item, the window of course disappears... which is not fun. So, how can i solve it?

Comment: So when do you want the "window" to close?

Comment: perhaps allow me to view it once with my mouse, after that, it can close again.

Comment: Eh.. can you be more specific? What happens if you hover on another item before you close the first?

Comment: well since each item will have its own window, if i would hover over one item, and then go to the next, the first window should close

Comment: Also hovering on item 1 should open `info-1`, hovering on item 2 opnens `info-2`... right?

Comment: yes it should work in both directions, if you have a solution please post it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**UPDATED**

I would make one function to handle the action you want for these. Make sure the 'info' divs are in the same order as the 'pop' li's

Here is an example [**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/videsignz/FrKBJ/2/)

```
<div id="pop">
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="info"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
<div class="info"></div>
```

Then use this jquery

```
$('#pop li').mouseover(function() {
    $('.info').hide();
    var x = $(this).index();
    $('.info').eq(x).show();
});

$('.info').mouseout(function(){
    $(this).hide();
});
```

Comment: that is exactly what I have right now... That window wont stay open as I hover out from the item. I need it to stay open so that I can access the "info1, ..."

Comment: @DinoExcel Here you go...I updated the answer and fiddle for you! :)